# imagecreatefromstring changes image color

Tags: php, gd

I'm having issues with image resizing in PHP; it seems like from the moment I load an image using `imagecreatefromstring` or `imagecreatefrompng`, the colors change and become faded.

I know I have to use `imagecreatetruecolor` to create the destination image, but I don't even get to this point.

Here's a few examples to explain the results I am getting:

```php
// This results in a discolored / faded image
$image = imagecreatefrompng('/path/to/my/image.png');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
die();
```

```php
// This also results in a discolored / faded image
$image = imagecreatefrompng('/path/to/my/image.png');
$info = getimagesize('/path/to/my/image.png');
$sourceWidth = $info[0];
$sourceHeight = $info[1];

$resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);
imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($resizedImage);
die();
```

```php
// Obviously, this works flawlessly.
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo file_get_contents('/path/to/my/image.png');
die();
```

Here's an example of before and after:
[image: Original on the left, faded on the right]

Obviously, I must be missing something, but I've looked at every SO question and answer I could find without finding any solution to my problem.

Have you ever had this issue? 
How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue might be related to color profiles as GD does not seem to have support for color profiles. This might happen if for example your images are in the Adobe RGB colorspace which has more color information than sRGB. Here's some more information on the subject:

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/ce-image/viewthread/1085

A possible solution is to use Photoshop to convert the image to sRGB (there's a "convert to sRGB" checkbox when exporting).

If that's not a possibility you can use [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) instead of GD, which (as mentioned in the above link) does support color profiles.

Comment: Well damn, you are right. I don't know how I didn't think to look into color profile support, but that's exactly it. GD does not support color profiles: it simply strips them. Imagick does support them however (that explains why it's referenced everywhere!).

I've therefore switched to Imagick's `cropThumbnailImage` for the resizing of the image, while keeping the rest of my initial processing pretty much the same. 

Thanks @ismael !

Comment: It's been over two years since this post; does anyone know if GD still doesn't support color profiles? A lot of software, including Chrome, has added such support in the past few years. I can't seem to find a straight answer on this presently, and I do see there are some many-year-old feature requests asking to add color profile support to GD.